# Как передать на Soap сервер параметры в формате Datetime?

Tags: delphi, soap

Требуется получить от сервера налоговой инспекции полученные мной от конкретного поставщика накладные в интервале времени. Без временного фильтра правильно работает, а если с фильтром, тогда не могу правильно передать дату не в формате `Datetime`, не в формате `XSDatetime`:

```
procedure TForm1.GetBuyerWaybillsClick(Sender: TObject);
        var WBS:WayBillsSoap;
          ToServ:get_buyer_waybills;
          FromServ:get_buyer_waybillsResponse;
          i:integer;
          DT: TDateTime;
          XSDT: TXSDateTime;
        begin

     TRY
WBS := GetWayBillsSoap(false,'',nil);
ToServ:=get_buyer_waybills.Create;

fmt.ShortDateFormat:='dd/MM/yyyy';
fmt.DateSeparator  :='/';
fmt.LongTimeFormat :='hh:mm:ss';
fmt.TimeSeparator  :=':';
//StrDate:='01/09/2015';
StrDate:='01/09/2015 01:04:56';
DT:=StrToDateTime(StrDate,Fmt);

ToServ.su:='BIDZINA01:201947554';
ToServ.sp:='mari555';
ToServ.seller_tin:='401964148';
//DateTimeToXSDateTime(DT);
ToServ.create_date_s.AsDateTime:=DT;
ToServ.create_date_e.AsDateTime:=DT;


FromServ:=WBS.get_buyer_waybills(ToServ);

Memo.Text := FromServ.get_buyer_waybillsResult.XMLNode.Xml;

  finally
    FreeAndNil(ToServ);
    FreeAndNil(FromServ);
    THTTPRIO(wbs).Free;
  end;
end;
```

Следующие операторы присваивания

```
ToServ.create_date_s.AsDateTime:=DT;
ToServ.create_date_e.AsDateTime:=DT;
```

Выводят:

> Access violation.... write of address 0*0000000c :

И при закрытии формы ещё выводится:

```
 an unexpected memory leak has ocurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:     
     13-20 bytes:TXSDateTime*1, 
     29-36 bytes: EAccessViolation*2, 
     69-76 bytes: UnicodeString*2.
     173-188 bytes: Unicodestring*2.
```

Описание функции такое (*soap 1.2*):

https://services.rs.ge/WayBillService/WayBillService.asmx?op=get_buyer_waybills

То есть, передаются параметры `create_date_s` и `create_date_e`  типа `datetime` (или, может быть, в формате `XSDatetime` - оба пробовал), а сервер возврашает в формате `XSDatetime` (`<CREATE_DATE>2012-04-03T12:23:52</CREATE_DATE>`):

```
 <WAYBILL>
    <ID>395946</ID><TYPE>2</TYPE>
    <CREATE_DATE>2012-04-03T12:23:52</CREATE_DATE> 
    <BUYER_TIN>201249558</BUYER_TIN>
    <BUYER_NAME>Фирма 1</BUYER_NAME>
    <SELLER_NAME>Фирма 2 +</SELLER_NAME>
    <SELLER_TIN>401964148</SELLER_TIN>
    ...
    <SELLER_ST>0</SELLER_ST></WAYBILL>
```

Ссылка на проект:

http://f-bit.ru/693399
https://mega.nz/#!fAk00KZK!wRdwCYcMVCV0YYoPIerTz4Wl1ofgA6NQ4NtWStq_lCQ

Comment: Хорошо бы сначала разобраться с AV. В большинстве случаев AV происходят от попыток доступа к уже несуществующему объекту. Лично мне очень не нравится конструкция `FreeAndNil()` в коде. Предлагаю для начала посмотреть как уничтожаются объекты и почему происходят утечки памяти.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown , ругается на операторе присваивания ToServ.create_date_s.AsDateTime:=DT; и после этого когда переходит на  FreeAndNil()  при уничтожении обьекта происходит утечка. Пока я хочу узнать причину ощибки при присваивании.

Comment: Очевидно `ToServ.create_date_s` у вас не инициализирован и равен `nil`.

Comment: @KromStern ,  su,sp, seller_tin тоже не инициализированы, но присваивание им значении не выводит ошибку!  может быть потому, что они string и они инициализированы пустой строкой(''), а create_date_s типа datetime и при создании равен nil? Тогда укажите,пожалуйста, как и где инициализировать? Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать точнее, в чем же именно у вас ошибка и уберите из вопроса все лишнее к ней не относящееся.

Comment: Следующие операторы присваивания

ToServ.create_date_s.AsDateTime:=DT;
ToServ.create_date_e.AsDateTime:=DT;

Выводят: " Access violation.... write of address 0*0000000c". Если из-за того, что create_date_s имеет тип datetime и при создании равен nil, тогда  как и где инициализировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать объекты сначала, потом присваивать:

```
ToServ.create_date_s:=TSXDateTime.Create;
ToServ.create_date_s.AsDateTime:=DT;
ToServ.create_date_e:=TSXDateTime.Create;
ToServ.create_date_e.AsDateTime:=DT;
```

Comment: Yura Ivanov, если я сначала должен создать обьект ToServ.create_date_s, в чем я с вами согласен, почему ToServ.create_su и  ToServ.create_sp не ругаются, я их тоже не создавал? Интересно просто, чтоб в будущем знал.

Comment: @davidkoko В приведенном в вопросе коде вы их не заполняете, а если будете заполнять и не создадите, тоже будут ругаться. У вас задаются строковые свойства su и sp, для которых создавать ничего не надо.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, что значит "заполнять"- присваивание значении? ToServ.sp:='mari555' оператор  присваивает своиству значение 'mari555', правильно? Но почему для ToServ.sp не надо писать оператор ToServ.create_date_s:=TSXDateTime.Create? В чём разница? Ведь оба они- и ToServ.sp и ToServ.create_date_s свойства, т.е. обьекти. Почему ToServ.sp не создаём, как создали ToServ.create_date_s?

Comment: ToServ.sp своиству  тоже присваивал значение('mari555') без создания обьекта оператором типа ToServ.create_date_s:=TSXDateTime.Create; !!!

Comment: @davidkoko посмотрите описания классов в `WayBillService.pas` (в частности `get_buyer_waybills` раз о нем речь идет). Обратите внимание на типы для каждого из свойств. Свойства это не объекты, а переменные, у каждого свой тип. Если у вас возникают затруднения чем отличаются классы от типов вообще (чем отличается String от TXMLData или от TXSDateTime в частсноти), то стоит почитать документацию, литературу...